# How to make material design full screen dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, fullscreen, material-design

I have tried many variants to create full screen dialog but I couldn't. I need something, like this, with two buttons:

[image]

Comment: just use another activity and open it with `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: Imho that's not a dialog but am Activity with a custom toolbar.

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/nikialeksey/FullScreenDialog)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want a a fullscreen dialog just extend the `Dialog` class and add a few tweaks. (You can also accomplish this without extending anything, but I thought you might want to keep everything in one place)

In your constructor you need to set the style (for your material look, or it can be an empty style tag):

```
super(context, R.style.DialogStyle);
```

you also need to set the view: (This is where you would define where/what those two buttons are)

```
setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
```

Finally, you might also need to modify the windows layout parameters:

```
getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

I have found on the devices I have tested that setting the style is the most important.

***EDIT***

To make it a little more clear you have two options:

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.YourStyle);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
        getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); //Optional
        //Any other code you want in your constructor
    }
}
```

Then when you want to show it:

```
//Inside your activity
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(this); //Assuming you are in an activity 'this' is your context
dialog.show();
```

Or you can just do this:

```
Dialog normalDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.YourStyle);
normalDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
normalDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I didn't understand where need to use this code: super(context, R.style.DialogStyle)

Comment: If you don't know where that would go, you need to do some more research on android development. But I added some edits to help you out a little more.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! It's what i need. And if somebody takes this error: android.viewWindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application, just use YourActivity.this instead this or getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using a new activity. Set the HomeAsUp indicator to whatever you want, then the Save button could be a single menu item set to show ifRoom.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)

android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]

Comment: Where need to set the HomeAsUpIndicator? Cause if I use getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator, I take error. Min API in my project 15, but this method need 18.

Comment: Use `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to display a full screen dialog without action bar:

```
//Display fullscreen without actionbar
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
    } else {
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
    }
```